# Exporting a table from a Backand app and importing it into another Backand app

Tags: backand

So here is my scenario: I have two apps in Backand: stagingApp and myApp. stagingApp has all the data, configurations and the model of our app. myApp is just an app I created for testing things without having to affect the model or data from stagingApp.

I was able to export the model and the configurations from stagingApp and import them into myApp. Now I need to export at least one table from it too to proceed with my testing. I can't find any button or obvious way to do that from the Backand UI. I know I could write a script that does this automatically, but I was wondering if there is an obvious or easier way I am missing on the Backand UI to export this table from stagingApp and import it into myApp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import data from a single table, you can follow these steps:

1. Issue a GET request to stagingApp on the object you are trying to export - you can set the pageSize query string object to request as mush as 1000 records.
2. Save the JSON response to your clipboard or a JSON file
3. Open myApp and go to the data tab of the object you are trying to import the data to, click the 'Upload data using JSON' button and drop the JSON from the clipboard, or click to upload the file.
4. click the 'upload' button

you can also explore the [bulk operation](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/bulk/)